# My posts page is missing the page title

Tags: posts, customization, title, blog

I cannot for the life of me figure out why a title is not showing up on my blog page. I want to be able to have a title and maybe even some descriptive text below instead of just jumping into the posts.

I don't really have experience with .php and behavioural coding so any help would be majorly appreciated.

I am using the XTheme PRO.

http://swift6000.staging.wpengine.com/news/

Thanks,

Yana

Answer (score 0):

The display of 'things' on your blog page is usually dependent on the theme. You can verify this by switching to one of the 'twenty' default themes and redisplay the page. If the title appears, then you have verified that the problem is a theme problem.

If you verify a problem with the theme, then contact the theme's support page. (Also, make sure that all updates are installed - WordPress, Themes, and Plugins - via the Update page on the Admin pages.)